# Faster way to build text file in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 3d numpy arrays, call them a and b, 512x512x512. I need to write them to a text file:

```
a1 b1
a2 b2
a3 b3
...
```

This can be accomplished with a triple loop:

```
lines = []
for x in range(nx):
    for y in range(ny):
        for z in range(nz):
            lines.append('{} {}'.format(a[x][y][z], b[x][y][z])
print('\n'.join(lines))
```

But this is brutally slow (10 minutes when I'd prefer a few seconds on a mac pro).

I am using python 3.6, latest numpy, and am happy to use other libraries, build extensions, whatever is necessary. What is the best way to get this faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `np.stack` and reshape the array to (-1, 2) (two columns) array, then use `np.savetxt`:

```
a = np.arange(8).reshape(2,2,2)
b = np.arange(8, 16).reshape(2,2,2)

np.stack([a, b], axis=-1).reshape(-1, 2)

#array([[ 0,  8],
#       [ 1,  9],
#       [ 2, 10],
#       [ 3, 11],
#       [ 4, 12],
#       [ 5, 13],
#       [ 6, 14],
#       [ 7, 15]])
```

Then you can save the file as:

```
np.savetxt("*.txt", np.stack([a, b], axis=-1).reshape(-1, 2), fmt="%d")
```

Comment: Wow I definitely could have googled that one, thank you for the complete example!

Comment: @Henry you almost *never* should be writing for-loops with `numpy`. At the very least, it is admitting defeat!

Answer (score 1):

you could use flatten() and dstack(), see example below

```
a = np.random.random([5,5,5]).flatten()
b = np.random.random([5,5,5]).flatten()
c = np.dstack((a,b))
print c
```

will result in

```
[[[ 0.31314428  0.35367513]
  [ 0.9126653   0.40616986]
  [ 0.42339608  0.57728441]
  [ 0.50773896  0.15861347]
....
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit difficult to understand your problem without knowing what kind of data you have in those three arrays, but it looks like `numpy.savetxt` could be useful for you.

Here's how it works:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(range(10))
np.savetxt("myfile.txt", a)
```

And here's the documentation:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Comment: But savetxt expects a 2d array